# baseless merge and subsequent reverse-integration merge

Tags: merge, azure-devops

With the following structure:

```
$/Main
$/Main/File001.txt

$/DisconnectedBranch
$/DisconnectedBranch/File001.txt
```

What I have done so far:
I've done a baseless merge from $/Main down to $/DisconnectedBranch....(thus establishing a relationship)

I properly resolved any conflicts for "File001.txt".
I committed changes.

Then: I made a change to:
$/DisconnectedBranch/File001.txt

and checked File001.txt (into $/DisconnectedBranch/)...(with Changeset 333)

Should I be able to now do a reverse-integration-merge back to $/Main?

Unfortunately, when I run:

```
"tf.exe" merge /recursive "C:\MyWorkspace\DisconnectedBranch\" "C:\MyWorkspace\Main\"
```

or

```
"tf.exe" merge /recursive /version:C333~C333 "C:\MyWorkspace\DisconnectedBranch\" "C:\MyWorkspace\Main\"
```

I am getting this:

```
There is no pending change for '$/Main/'
```

and this error:

```
The item $/Main is not a branch of $/DisconnectedBranch/.
```

I thought when I successfully performed the baseless merge, reverse-integration would be available.

Or am I too wishful-thinking?

Thanks.

FYI: I've spent a few days prototyping this.  Aka, my question is not due to a lack of trying and experimenting.  THANKS for any input.

Comment: Are you sure about the 'C' in 'C333'? Have you tried only 333?

Comment: Yep. 2nd example : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I was also getting the "The item $/Main is not a branch of" error. Then I tried to merge from inside Visual Studio. When I came to the dialog where you specify source and target branches, I suddenly realized that I was using wrong source and target. When I switched to the correct ones, it worked. I would recommend you try this option.